# Does Hibernate return null or empty collection if table in relation is empty?

Tags: java, hibernate

I was curious about something. Let's say we have a simple relation between *Employee* and *Phone*:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name="EMP_ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phones;
  ...
}
@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
  private Employee owner;
  ...
}
```

Let's assume that an *Employee* has no phones, no entries in the *Phone* table.
If I were to have a piece of code that gets the phones of an *Employee* and iterates over them for whatever reason

```
for (Phone phone : employee.getPhones())
{
     ...
}
```

Would the getter retun NULL or an empty Collection and would the getching strategy play a part.

If I remember correctly, hibernate has its own implementation of collection using proxies and for *LAZY* fetch, it instantiates with one of those and when needed retrieves the data from the table (correct If I am wrong). So would at the time the getter is called try to retrieve the data from the table, get an empty set as a result and return an empty collection. (This is what I think). Or should I always check if the result of the getter is *NULL* or not?

Comment: Very probably an empty list. Returning `null` instead of an empty list is a bad practice.

Comment: You can always make check in your getter and return empty list if phones is null

Comment: Yeah, I am going to eventually but unfortunately I don't have access right now to my laptop and wont for some time. Was discussing some things with some friends and we needed to know. I know it sounds lazy but if I could check it right now I would... Sorry

Comment: This seems like one of those cases where the best way to answer the question is to just *try it and see what happens*.

Comment: it is also good practice to initialize array as instance variable in the entity: private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>(); so u know that u prevent npe

Comment: Finally managed to try it and it returns null. Now I might have some kind of other error (don't think so) but I will look into it. While debugging I put a breakpoint right after the HQL query returns. To be accurate I have two relations like these, phonesPersonal and phonesBusiness, and the second one is the empty table. The phonesPersonal is populated and phonesBusiness is returning a lazy exception error. There is a chance the personal is populated because of the debugger (when pressing on the member I think it might fetch them). But after a few lines one is a list the other is a null.

Comment: I should mention that when looking at it on the debugger and it had the error, the type was reading as a persistence bag which is a Hibernate structure if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Since those collections are lazy by default `employee.getPhones()` should return a proxy for that collection (e.g. `PersistentList` or similar) which loads the list elements when you access the list.

Additionally, because `Phone` is the owner of the relation Hibernate won't know whether there are any phones for an employee or not so it has to assume the list exists - although it *might* be empty. That said it wouldn't make much sense for Hibernate to return null since:

- Hibernate would need to try and load the phones first to see that there are none
- to implement lazy loading of the collection `getPhones()` must not return null but a proxy
- returning null would be bad practice anyways (the list would still exist, it's just empty)
- if the list was null you could not add a phone and let Hibernate use cascading etc. to automatically persist that change (thanks to [Gimby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424903/gimby) for pointing that out)

Using eager loading shouldn't change that. Hibernate would know that there is no phone for the employee but returning null instead of an empty list, which also would express that there are no phones, would still make little sense (think of allowing to add phones for a loaded employee, differences in code where you'd not need them if null was used for eager fetching, etc.).