# Does JPA return "null" or empty collection for a collection property that is empty in the DB?

Tags: jpa, collections, null, language-lawyer

If I have a JPA entity containing a collection field, such as

```
public class Post {    
  // [...]
  @OneToMany
  private List<String> tags;
```

the corresponding database schema will typically contain a separate table for storing the tags, where each record contains one tag and a foreign key reference to the "Post" table.

Now when I load a "Post" entity from the database which has no tags (i.e. no corresponding "tag" records exist), what will the value of `Post.tags` be? Will it be set to `null`, or to an empty `List`? Or is this undefined?

I could not find this in the JPA specification.

---

*Note:* This is the same question like [Does Hibernate return null or empty collection if table in relation is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104912/does-hibernate-return-null-or-empty-collection-if-table-in-relation-is-empty), only for the JPA spec instead of for Hibernate specifically.

I know that most JPA implementations (at least Hibernate and EclipseLink) will return an empty collection - I'm interested in whether this is specified anywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [JPA 2.1 spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf):

> **2.9 Entity Relationships**
>
> If there are no associated entities for a multi-valued relationship of an entity fetched from the database,
> the persistence provider is responsible for returning an empty collection as the value of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I only searched the JPA spec for "null" and "empty", that's why I didn't find it.